# How is open nfc organized and how is open API used in application programming?

Tags: nfc

I have downloaded and read a source folder of Open NFC latest core package but I am very curious about the structure of Open NFC program and also Open NFC API, I am a begginer in this section, please help, thanks

Answer (score -1):

u can create your nfc tag in both android and blackberry(version os should be 7.1.0) check this link out in andrroid and blackberry

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Reading-and-Writing-NFC-Smart-Tags/ta-p/1379453

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/nfc/advanced-nfc.html